# How do I make a logical "OR" out of the "bool" query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: json, database, search, elasticsearch

In the Elasticsearch documentation, it says the "Or Query" is deprecated and to use the "bool" query instead: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-query.html

But I'm not sure how to make a logical "OR" using the "bool" query. I tried:

```
query: {
    bool: {
        must: [
            { match: { title: 'some title'}},
            { match: { author: 'some author'}}
        ]
    }
}
```

This matches the title being 'some title' AND the author being 'some author', but how do I convert this into an OR express? Like I want it to match the title being 'some title' OR the author being 'some author'. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just replace you must with should and add the operator:

```
query: {
    bool: {
        should: [
            { match: { title: {query:'some title', operator: 'AND'}},
            { match: { author: {query: 'some author', operator: 'AND'}}
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this? What does the should and the AND operator do exactly?

Comment: And to add an "AND" with this, I use the "must" operator? Like for example, if I wanted the logic above AND I wanted some other logic, do I use the 'must' along with the 'should'?

Comment: It might be smart to read the docs, they explain this very well. But operator and means both terms some and title need to be present. With the OR only one of them needs to be present. With a should without a must, at least one of the conditions must match. If you want another condition to match, you can add a must. Than you have to add a minimum_should_match to the should part. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html