# How to get the JSON for an ElasticSearch BoolQuery

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Given an instance of BoolQuery, how can I find out the JSON string that will be sent to the ES server?

Note that I am using ES7.

I tried toString(), but it returns something like "co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.BoolQuery@3cec79d3".

I see that there is a serialize() method, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to construct the two arguments (JsonGenerator and JsonpMapper).

I tried Amit's suggestion of getting the json from the SearchRequest object's source, but it does not seem to work. For example in the sample code below, the last line raises a NullPointerException because sReq.source() returns null.

```
SearchRequest sReq = SearchRequest.of(s -> s
  .index("products")
  .query(q -> q
      .match(t -> t
          .field("name")
          .query("hello")
      )
    )
  );

  String sReqJson = sReq.source().toString();
```

Comment: [check this, it may help](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37705718/16528677)

Answer (score 0):

You must be having the search request object if you are using Elasticsearch 7 client, you can use `searchRequest.source().toString()` to get the search JSON on it.

Comment: Thx for your reply Amit. I tried what you suggest but it does not seem to work. See the addition I made to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    JsonGenerator generator = JacksonJsonProvider.provider().createGenerator(writer);
    boolQuery.serialize(generator, new JacksonJsonpMapper());
    generator.flush();
    String json = writer.toString();
```